# My re-CAPTCHA doesn´t work

Tags: php

I use re-CAPTCHA on my website but it doesn't work when I click LOGIN it says Robot verification failed, please try again I don´t know how to fix it... every time :/

Thanks for help.

If you have better script send me please.

```
        if(isset($_POST['g-recaptcha-response']) && !empty($_POST['g-recaptcha-response']))
    {
        $secret = '**************';

        $verifyResponse = file_get_contents('https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/siteverify?secret='.$secret.'&response='.$_POST['g-recaptcha-response']);
        $responseData = json_decode($verifyResponse);

        if($responseData->success)
        { 

        }else{
                echo "<div class='container'><div class='alert alert-danger'><p>Robot verification failed, please try again.</p></div>";
            }
    }else{
            echo "<div class='container'><div class='alert alert-danger'><p>Please click on the reCAPTCHA box.</p></div>";
    }
```

Comment: you have answers below; if it solved it, you should mark it as solved.

Comment: "doesn't work" means nothing, just like the question you posted (and deleted) a few minutes ago with the same thing; quit trolling will ya? and using Stack as your free debugging service.

Answer (score 0):

Here is how I handle Google Re-Captcha on the Server:

```
//process captia response with a custom method.
$captcha = checkCaptia($_POST['g-recaptcha-response']);

if ($captcha){
    mailLead();
}
else{
   header('location: https://...');
   die();
}
```

Method to handle captcha check...

```
function checkCaptia($captcha){ 
    $url = 'https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/siteverify';

    $data = array(
        'secret'=>';jaskdf;asdkjf',
        'response'=>$captcha,
        'remoteip'=>$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']
    );

    $options = array(
        'http' => array(
        'header'  => "Content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded\r\n",
        'method'  => 'POST',
        'content' => http_build_query($data)
        )
    );
    $context  = stream_context_create($options);
    $result = json_decode(file_get_contents($url, false, $context),TRUE);

    return $result;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I use ReCaptcha package for Composer when handling captchas.

If you don't know what Composer is, I suggest you head to [http://composer.org/](http://composer.org)

Composer is a PHP dependency manager and it can be really useful when building modern PHP apps.

ReCaptcha Package: https://packagist.org/packages/google/recaptcha

Code samples are also included in the link.